# How to verbalize the correct statement of a measure in mixed units

Tags: phrase-requests, terminology

I want help phrasing the instructions in a math question. The issue is the correct way to express mixed units.

For example, if an answer is “25 inches,” I don’t want to accept “25 inches” or “1 foot 13 inches,” but only “2 feet 1 inch.”

I guess you might say that I want the total number of units to be small as possible. But I don’t think anyone would understand what I meant by that. Similarly, I don't think it would do to say that I want the answer "simplified."

Comment: Simple solution:  Ask for the answer in meters.

Answer (score 1):

Simply state:

> "Express the answer in *feet and inches*"

As part of the question. Valid answers could be "25 inches" or "2 feet 1 inch", and with this statement, you eliminate the former.

Anyone who answers with "1 foot 13 inches" simply misunderstands how units work. It’s like saying "twenty-thirteen" when you mean thirty-three. Or expressing "2 hours 30 minutes" as "1 hour 90 minutes".

Comment: So. 2.0833 feet or 25 inches....

Comment: Well, @Jim, I guess there’s also the logical implications of "and" and "or", and maybe this question shouldn’t test that.  If the question specifies "and", then it seem appropriate to specify a single quantity which uses both units. Alternatively, I suppose you could put "___feet, ____ inches".